# std::rbegin and std::rend function in GCC 4.9 and clang 3.5

Tags: c++, gcc, iterator, clang, c++14

I have been using std::rbegin and std::rend in MSVC 2013. When I tried to compile my code using GCC 4.9.1 or clang 3.5.0, both tell me that 'rbegin' and 'rend' are not part of namespace 'std'.

See the code example below. Am I doing something wrong or are they simply not yet implemented in GCC and clang?

```
// test.cpp

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::vector<int> test = {1, 2, 3 ,4, 5};
    for (auto it = std::rbegin(test); it != std::rend(test); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

GCC output:

```
g++ --std=c++14 test.cpp -o test && ./test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:10:20: error: ‘rbegin’ is not a member of ‘std’
     for (auto it = std::rbegin(test); it != std::rend(test); ++it) {
                    ^
test.cpp:10:45: error: ‘rend’ is not a member of ‘std’
     for (auto it = std::rbegin(test); it != std::rend(test); ++it) {
                                             ^
```

clang output is similar, generated with:

```
clang++ --std=c++14 test.cpp -o test && ./test
```

Comment: You're comparing GCC with Clang but both use libstdc++ by default and it's really the standard library implementations you should be comparing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work with Clang 3.5 using the `-std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++` option. See this [**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8b4e9cc3365d0f9). I think the libstdc++ library support for `rbegin()` and `rend()` is not yet complete as version 4.9.2 (and it is also [**not yet implemented in the upcoming gcc 5.0**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uZQnWlgq7skDdSPI) release).

**UPDATE**: it now works in the gcc 5.0 trunk release.

Comment: Right, so it's just libstdc++ that doesn't have it yet.

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) it is a new C++14 feature. I'm still surprised it hasn't been implemented yet though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the upcoming gcc 5 will have it. Haven't found an online compiler to demonstrate that.

Comment: @TemplateRex [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/). Although as of 1/12/2015, it doesn't appear to be implemented.

Comment: The [gcc 5 changes page](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx) claims to have it in the next libstdc++: "*global functions cbegin, cend, rbegin, rend, crbegin, and crend for range access to containers, arrays and initializer lists.*"  Running the code in your final Wandbox now works.